# Precision to_double

Tags: cgal

In this CGAl program, I use Exact_predicates_exact_constructions kernel, as I want accuracy in my computations. I have a Point_3 vector `std::vector< Point_3> points;`  and I want to copy the x coordinates in an array. By doing as follows, do I lose precision?

```
double A [points.size()];
 for (int i = 0;
  i != points.size();
 ++i)
 {
A[i] = CGAL::to_double(points[i].x());                   
}
```

Do I also lose precision when using CGAL::to_double on a quotient? Is it possible to create a plane as follows, without doing the conversion?
EDIT:

```
 // choose exact integral type
#ifdef CGAL_USE_GMP
#include <CGAL/Gmpz.h>
typedef CGAL::Gmpz ET;
#else
#include <CGAL/MP_Float.h>
typedef CGAL::MP_Float ET;
#endif

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel  K;
typedef K::Plane_3                                         Plane_3;
typedef CGAL::Quadratic_program_solution<ET>               Solution;
typedef CGAL::Quotient<ET>                                 Quotient;
//
// lp is a linear program with double matrices A,b,c
Solution s = CGAL::solve_linear_program(lp, ET());
Solution::Variable_value_iterator it = s.variable_values_begin();
 const Quotient a=*it;
 const Quotient b=*(++it);
 const Quotient c=*(++it);

Plane_3 new_plane=Plane_3(a,b,-1,c);
```

When compiling I get an error message starting like this:
error: no matching function for call to ‘CGAL::Plane_3 < CGAL::Epeck >::Plane_3(const Quotient&, const Quotient&, int, const Quotient&)’

Comment: Yes, you lose precision when going from arbitrary exact rationals to double (which as limited precision).

Comment: I want to create a Plane_3 and use those rationals as parameters. Can use them without converting them to double first?

Comment: Yes, you can, and probably should. Is there something in the doc of CGAL that gave you the impression that you should use double? If so, please point out where that is so we can fix it.

Comment: There occurrs an error when I try to compile to program without converting to double, so that's what gave me the impression. I edited my question to cite some extra parts of my code , I 'd really appreciate it if you help me fix this

Comment: Don't try to guess a type like Quotient, just use K::FT to use whatever number type the kernel is using, same as you used K::Plane_3.

Comment: I don't understand how that fixes the problem. I m a newbie in CGAL, could you be more precise please?

Comment: `K::FT a = *it;` (Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel does not use `Quotient<Gmpz>` for numbers, and not all conversions between all possible number types are implemented). (I don't know what `Solution` is, so some tweak may be needed on that side as well, a [mcve] would have been nice)

Comment: Solution comes from typedef CGAL::Quadratic_program_solution<ET> 
As I saw on the manual the variable values are of quotient type, or am I wrong?

Comment: Anyway, the issue is converting from Quotient<ET> to K::FT. It seems that `K::FT(q.numerator())/K::FT(q.denominator())` works for that. You could try filing an issue on github asking for a constructor Gmpq(Quotient<Gmpz>) to simplify this process.